# Regex with -, ::, ( and )

Tags: java, regex

I need to split the string

> (age-is-25::OR::last_name-is-qa6)::AND::(age-is-20::OR::first_name-contains-test)

into

> string[0] = (age-is-25::OR::last_name-is-qa6)
>
> string[1] = AND
>
> string[2] = (age-is-20::OR::first_name-contains-test)

I tried writing so many regex expressions, but nothing works as expected.

Using the following regex, Matcher.groupCount() which returns 2 but assigning results to an arraylist returns null as the elements.

> Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\)::)?|(::\\()?");

I tried to split it using ):: or ::(.

I know the regex looks too stupid, but being a beginner this is the best I could write.

Comment: Generalization of this problem is equivalent to parsing expressions with regexp, which is not possible: regex is not powerful enough for that.

Comment: It's not stupid if you actually tried something :)  Great job for trying something first before asking.

Comment: how can it be splitted by `::` only around `AND` without putting that `AND` into that splitter??

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need a regex, or is it just because you think that will be easier than parsing the string yourself? In my experience, string parsing code is often quicker to write and easier to debug than regexes.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight not necessarily, if it is about splitting things between brackets from the rest.

Comment: @DanielPryden : Initially I tried parsing the string, but since the string is too complex, I thought regex would better work here.

Comment: @Catherine: Given the structure of the string you've shown, a simple lexer (which you can do with a regex, although you don't need to) combined with a simple [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) should do the trick.  Unfortunately I'm typing on my phone at the moment, or else I'd give you an example.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead and lookbehind to match the first and last parentheses.

```
String str = "(age-is-25::OR::last_name-is-qa6)::AND::(age-is-20::OR::first_name-contains-test)";

for (String s : str.split("(?<=\\))::|::(?=\\()"))
    System.out.println(s);
```

Outputs:

```
(age-is-25::OR::last_name-is-qa6)
AND
(age-is-20::OR::first_name-contains-test)
```

---

*Just a note however: It seems like you are parsing some kind of recursive language. Regular expressions are not good at doing this. If you are doing advanced parsing I would recommend you to look at other parsing methods.*

Comment: Funny how this is the first answerer that doesn't do a wild guess. He is clearly more familiar with advanced regex and still he tests. The rest is just like "try this, and if you're lucky it'll work".

Comment: @dacwe really one of smart answer buddy. +1 to it.

Comment: @dacwe: Thanks a lot! Btw, I dont understand the usage of ?<= and ?= in the regex. I have never seen those in any of the tutorials. Can u please explain or else can u point out some url from where I could get some info on that? Thanks again.

Comment: I think http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html talks about that. Any other good tutorials?

Comment: @Catherine, yes, read that site (I have). The thing to remember that the "lookaround" isn't matched into your result, hence just a check.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like a big part of your stress comes from the need for escaping special characters in your search term. I highly recommend to not do manual escaping of special characters, but instead to use [Pattern.quote(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) for the escaping.

Answer (score 1):

This should works

```
 "(?<=\\))::|::(?=\\()"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
textString.split("\\)::|::\\(")
```

should work.

Comment: backslash comes twice...dont know why formatting is removing my second backslash

Comment: If formatting is messing with your code make it a code block, or use ` ` ` those `like this`

Comment: It will not include the ) in first string and ( in 3rd string

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I dropped the idea of parsing since the string appeared too complex. But as Chandra Sekhar suggested, it missed out the "(" from first string and ")" from last string. Is it a good idea to replace ")::" with "))::" and "::(" with "::((" before parsing?

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you.

```
\)::|::\(
```